# PDO fetchAll(); Select Statement while Binding Parameters

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to make a search feature on my website using PDO. I wrote something and I would like to know if it looks right. My website allows people to post things and this code is to give users the ability to search for posts.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONTAINS (post, :search)");
$statement->execute(array(':search' => $_POST["search"]));
$row = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach ($statement as $row)
{
    echo $row['post'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL is most common, but it doesn't have a `CONTAINS()` function.

Comment: @Barmar I use MySQL for my database.

Comment: Use `LOCATE()` instead of `CONTAINS()`

Comment: @Barmar Oh, are there any alternatives to CONTAINS()?

Comment: Don't you try queries by hand when you're designing?